# Review 5-stars Multiclassification Model

Tags: logistic, svm, naive-bayes

So I'm super new to DataScience World. And I'm Trying to do a TextMining Work.
My goal is by reading user's reviews to predict their rating to a tech product.

Problem? Multiclassification model with 50% accurancy in Naive Bayes and SVM and with 56% in Logistic Regression.

I have already used an spell_checker; tf-idf; stemming and an Emotional lexicon. But I didn't improve that much... So I was hoping that someone could actually help me out.

Is there a better model? What is the better way to approach this problem? How should I measure the error?

Thansk in advance!